# Excel VBA - Creating Click Event on Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to setup a report that has line item details summarized by a subgroup for each. On each line, I want to add a checkbox, with the subtotal of each group being a "master" checkbox that would change all of the corresponding checkboxes if it's clicked.

My solution is to create an individual click event for each master checkbox that updates everything with a similar name (i.e. line items have checkbox names File1_1, File1_2, and subtotal line has name Master_File1). To create each report, I run the data through a processor spreadsheet, so each of these click events needs to be added through VBA.

When I try to apply the event procedure, I get an "Event handler is invalid" error on the `.CreateEventProc` line. The first snippet below is the subprocedure to apply the macro (the proc_lines code has been tested and works how I want it to, just can't get it implemented). I originally received an error for trying to pass the worksheet name I gave it ("Ops Staff 1"), so I changed the sheet name to be the VBA type ("Sheet3")

```
Private Sub add_master_checkbox_module(sheet_name As String, report_book As Workbook, checkbox_name as String)

    Dim VB_proj As Object
    Dim VB_comp As Object
    Dim code_mod As Object
    Dim line_number As Long
    Dim proc_lines As String

    On Error GoTo Error_ClickEvent

    Set VB_proj = report_book.VBProject
    Set VB_comp = VB_proj.VBComponents(sheet_name)
    Set code_mod = VB_comp.CodeModule
    
    proc_lines = "Dim cbx As CheckBox" & vbLf & _
                "Dim val As Long " & vbLf & _
                "Dim grp As String " & vbLf & _
                vbLf & _
                vbTab & "grp = Application.Caller " & vbLf & _
                vbTab & "val = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(grp).Value" & vbLf & _
                vbTab & "grp = Split(grp, ""_"")(1)" & vbLf & _
                vbLf & _
                vbTab & "For Each cbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes" & vbLf & _
                    vbTab & vbTab & "If cbx.Name Like grp & ""_*"" Then" & vbLf & _
                        vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "cbx.Value = val" & vbLf & _
                    vbTab & vbTab & "End If" & vbLf & _
                vbTab & "Next cbx"

    With code_mod
    Debug.Print checkbox_name
        line_number = .CreateEventProc("Click", checkbox_name)
        line_number = line_number + 2
        .InsertLines line_number, proc_lines
    End With

Error_ClickEvent:
    MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Below is the part of the main procedure where the checkbox is created and the above is called. `rg` refers to a range in a for loop.

```
With temp_sheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Left:=rg.Left + (rg.Width / 2#) - 12, Top:=rg.Top, Width:=12, Height:=rg.Height)
    .Caption = ""
    .LinkedCell = rg
    .Name = checkbox_name
End With
Call add_master_checkbox_module("Sheet" & sheet_number, report_book, checkbox_name)
```

Comment: `CheckBoxes.Add` creates a Forms checkbox, not an ActiveX checkbox.  A Forms checkbox doesn't have events, but you can link it to a sub.

Comment: @TimWilliams, when I create the event procedure manually I'm able to set up a click event. I tried to switch it to an ActiveX box and it creates the procedure, but I now get an error on `Application.Caller` in the first piece of code.

Comment: You could link all (Forms) checkboxes to the same macro, and use `Application.Caller` to figure out which one was clicked.  No Need for separate methods for each checkbox.